# I was wondering what scale the following notes are and how to transpose them on an alto saxophone (B, C#, D#, E, F#, G#, A#, B)

Tags: theory, scales

I have been asked to play an audio recording of the scale (B,C#,D#,E,F#,G#,A#,B) but i am not sure which scale this is. It would also be helpful if anyone knew how to transpose these notes on an alto saxophone as well.

Comment: The person who asked you to make the recording is the best one to tell you whether they want the written or concert pitches. How could we know what they are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a B major scale, which technically should be G# for Alto Saxophone, but that key is considered only as theoretical (it would have 6 sharps and an F double sharp), so it is normally transposed as Ab.

Answer (score 0):

This is the major B scale. When you play a C on your instrument you get the tone with a pitch of Eb, i.e. a minor 3rd above C. Thus you have to play the Ab major scale to play B major. (To play a C you must play A - B is a semitone lower than C => Ab)

Answer (score 0):

The key with 5 sharps in is key B major. I expect that's what the concert pitch is that you've been asked to provide.

Since the alto sax is a *transposing* instrument, it's no good playing those actual notes, as if you were reading them off a chart. So, what you would do, is play the scale of A♭ major, as if you were reading from a chart, and those key B notes would be sounded. So, write (if you like) A♭, B♭, C, D♭, E♭, F, G, A♭ on a stave, and play them.